# Incomplete attachments remain attached to the mail

Tags: email, filter, email-attachments

I am using mimedefang filtering tool. In the configuration, I strip out all the attachments and forward it to another address. For particular sender, I can see milter changes the header Content-Type from application/pdf and multipart-mixed. In the received email on outlook, when I open the pdf using text editor (it contains content like ("This is a multi-part message in MIME format..." followed by some random numbers "------------=_1525668389-64274-8--").

Can anyone guess why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-part messages (like those with attachments) have their parts divided by a `boundary`. This `boundary` is between 1 and 70 characters and must not appear anywhere in the anywhere within the encapsulated parts of the message (between boundaries).

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html><head></head><body>This is the HTML body of the message.</body></html>
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body of the message.
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgPC9oZWFkPgogIDxib2R5PgogICAgPHA+VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUg
Ym9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZS48L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==
--gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p--
```

I suspect that somewhere between mimedefang and your milter configuration, the boundaries are getting mangled or included into the attachment can causing them to be corrupted.